# Is there an easy way to have a Winforms LinkLabel just show as a label?

Tags: winforms

I'm looking into adding a link for a project I'm working on and was wondering if there was an easy way to have a `LinkLabel` (or potentially another control if there's one I can use for this) to just appear as a label under certain conditions?

I've looked into the documentation a bit and didn't see anything that stands out to me as a way to do this. Realistically I could just set the `Enabled`, `DisabledLinkColor`, and `LinkBehavior` properties to have it appear to be a label or just have both a `LinkLabel` and `Label` and change the `Visible` properties on each accordingly. However, neither of these solutions sound ideal to me. So if there is a different way to perform this functionality any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero the length of the [LinkLabel.LinkArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkarea?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) property to disable the link behavior and display it as a standard `Label` control. Reset the length to the text length to restore the default behavior.

```cs
 [DesignerCategory("code")]
 public class LinkLabelEx : LinkLabel
 {
     private bool _linkEnabled = true;

     [DefaultValue(true)]
     public bool LinkEnabled
     {
         get => _linkEnabled;
         set
         {
             if (_linkEnabled != value)
             {                    
                 _linkEnabled = value;
                 LinkArea = new LinkArea(0, value ? Text.Length : 0);
             }
         }
     }        
 }
```